# IE8 browser tab crashes when using PIE.htc in css files

Tags: jquery, html, css, css3pie

I seem to be getting an issue when using PIE.htc in my css files on IE8 only. It crashes the browser tab, event viewer says:

Faulting application iexplore.exe, version 8.0.6001.18702, faulting module mshtml.dll, version 8.0.6001.18702, fault address 0x0020fbd7.

If I remove the refs to PIE.htc in the css files, it loads without error.

I'm not sure but this may be related to jquery 1.7.2 - if I stop jquery loading, it also works. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: I experimented issues using jQuery animation on elements which have `PIE.htc` attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with PIE and jQuery, as shown [here](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=779). What specifically are you trying to do with jQuery. Does it happen if you don't actually call any jQuery methods, i.e. if you literally just include a script element pointing to jQuery it stops working? Or are you trying to use a particular jQuery method..? Any errors in the console..?

Comment: Thanks for the link - yeah looks like that's my problem. I can't remove all the jquery calls cos it would take me all week and it's not worth the hassle.

Comment: no problem :) I use jQuery in pretty much every build I do these days, so PIE is never something I can really use. There are alternatives though, what did you want to use PIE for? A great little library that adds a lot of CSS3 selectors to old IE is selectivzr (http://selectivizr.com/), which works very well with jQuery

Comment: Cheers I'll have a look at that